# Adding boolean column to rails database prevents messages from being saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, boolean

```
  def create 
    msg = current_user.msgs.build(params[:msg])
    msg.message = msg.message
    msg.created_at = Time.now # HACK
    if msg.save
    else
      flash[:error] = "Your article must contain some text."
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

This is my controller code to save a message, it worked before I tried `rails g migration add_anonymous_to_msg anonymous:boolean` and `rake db:migrate` Now I get the error "your article must contain some text" which means the messages are no longer being saved or the text is not being recognised. I tried removing the column and my schema.rb says that it no longer exists but the error still persists.

Does anyone know what might be the problem? Thanks

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? And why do you feel the need to hack the `created_at` time? Your model and migration would be helpful as well.

Comment: Maybe you could try `flash[:error] = "Your article must contain some text. #{msg.errors.collect {|attr, msg| [attr,msg].join(":")}.join(", ")}"` to see where the problem is. (edited: there was a } and a join missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
def create 
  @message = current_user.messages.build(params[:message])
  unless @message.save
    flash[:error] = "Your article must contain some text."
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Removes the need for the empty if block.

Comment: Thanks for simplifying the code but it still doesnt work. The problem was caused by adding the boolean column to the database, it prevents @message save, resulting in the flash[:error]

Comment: Is the column still on the table?  Did you make it a non null column and its not defaulted?

Comment: No, schema.rb says that the column is not in the table anymore.

Comment: Can you check the actual db table. You can execute 'describe TABLENAME' to get the info on the table.

Comment: The name of the table is "msgs", so do I type "describe msgs" in the rails dbconsole

Comment: First you should just build a message in the console and call .save! on it so you can see the actual AR error on the model.  And yes you would type describe msgs; in the dbconsole.

Comment: `macpro:site1 fred$ rails dbconsole
SQLite version 3.6.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> describe msgs;
SQL error: near "describe": syntax error.` I get this error?

Comment: OK, that confirms that the column no longer exists. Could you please help me to build a message in the console to check if that works? Thanks

Comment: just go into rails console and do Message.new, and start putting data into it.. when you are done just call msg.save! and you should get an exception telling you what failed.

Comment: I get the error `NameError: undefined local variable or method `msg' for main:Object` when I try to save

Comment: huh? In your rails console: msg = Message.new; msg.text = 'blah', msg.next_attr = 'nextval'; msg.save!

Comment: @user852974 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2454/discussion-between-jake-dempsey-and-user852974)

Comment: I tried that and I get  `=> "blah"` from the console, so there are no errors there.

Answer (score 0):

I really think a rewrite of your controller is required, its hard to read and there is a lot of code you don't need. Try something like this:

```
def create 
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  if @message.save
  else
    flash[:error] = "Your article must contain some text."
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Secondly, there is most likely an error message in your logs when you submit the form. Any chance you could post that?

Comment: That doesn't take care of the current user id, which is not a good thing to store on the form. Maybe current_user.msgs.new(params[:message]) would work.

Comment: The `current_user` is used so often it should be called from a helper and then referenced when you need to assign a user to a object like this: `@message.user = current_user`

Answer (score 0):

you really need to change this line

`flash[:error] = "Your article must contain some text."`

to

`flash[:error] = msg.errors.full_message`

from the error message you will know what exactly know what the problem is.